# Cron runs scheduled jobs run but last run not updated!

Tags: cron

On joomla 3.6.4 with php 5.6.30 and civiCRM 4.7.15 we have the above issue. Easycron is set to trigger every 2 minutes which it does. In civi settings scheduled jobs the last run date and time does not change for any of the 10 jobs.
When the job log is opened the job has been run according to the time stamp.
How do I get the last run time to agree with the log entry?????